# Unable to run python websockets on local network

Tags: python, websocket, local-network

I am creating a websocket using ip ="0.0.0.0" so it can be connected on the local network but unfortunately i am having problems doing so ,i am using ubuntu and also have tried to setup firewall rules for it using this command `sudo ufw allow 8050/tcp`
This socket is working fine on my local pc
but is not working for other devices on the network